# Why am I getting "Invalid argument to function" error on my query?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT qry_performPrep2Elo_wta.PK_G, IIf([ID1_ocEdge]>0,[ID1_ocStake],0) AS ocStake, IIf([ID1_ocEdge]>0,[ID1_ocStake]*([ID1_ocmktPr]-1)) AS ocPL
FROM tbl_G_ov_wta INNER JOIN qry_performPrep2Elo_wta ON tbl_G_ov_wta.PK_G = qry_performPrep2Elo_wta.PK_G
WHERE (((tbl_G_ov_wta.ID1_G_Tot_Ov)>=(SELECT Min_games_wta FROM [tbl_ref_games] WHERE Surface = "All surfaces")));
```

But I get an "Invalid argument to function" error. If I remove the WHERE clause and run the following:

```
SELECT qry_performPrep2Elo_wta.PK_G, IIf([ID1_ocEdge]>0,[ID1_ocStake],0) AS ocStake, IIf([ID1_ocEdge]>0,[ID1_ocStake]*([ID1_ocmktPr]-1)) AS ocPL
FROM tbl_G_ov_wta INNER JOIN qry_performPrep2Elo_wta ON tbl_G_ov_wta.PK_G = qry_performPrep2Elo_wta.PK_G;
```

Everything works fine. I investigated the WHERE clause and couldn't see a reason for an issue. Indeed, when I remove the IIF statements but include the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT qry_performPrep2Elo_wta.PK_G
FROM tbl_G_ov_wta INNER JOIN qry_performPrep2Elo_wta ON tbl_G_ov_wta.PK_G = qry_performPrep2Elo_wta.PK_G
WHERE (((tbl_G_ov_wta.ID1_G_Tot_Ov)>=(SELECT Min_games_wta FROM [tbl_ref_games] WHERE Surface = "All surfaces")));
```

Everything runs fine.

The field `PK_G` is a primary key common across both the table and the query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the zero here:

```
IIf([ID1_ocEdge]>0,[ID1_ocStake]*([ID1_ocmktPr]-1),0)
```

Comment: Great spot but sadly this didn't fix it :-(

Comment: There's some weird stuff going on in this sequence of queries. Have posted another issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525346/why-are-my-records-blank-in-my-access-query